# ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj) returning base class model when used on a proxy model object

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-1.7

I have a proxy model derived from another model. Now I create object of this proxy model and try to find out the content type object using ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj) it returns the base class content type object rather than giving me the proxy model content type. Im using django 1.7.8.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class ProxyModel(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

now i am getting an object of proxy model

```
proxy_obj = ProxyModel.objects.get(field1=1)
```

and trying to find the content type class of the proxy_obj

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(proxy_obj)
```

But this yields me the content type object of BaseModel instead of ProxyModel. Why is this behaving in a absurd way? Or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From django-docs for [`get_for_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentTypeManager.get_for_model) method:

> Takes either a model class or an instance of a model, and returns the
>   ContentType instance representing that model. `for_concrete_model=False`
>   allows fetching the `ContentType` of a proxy model.

You have to pass `for_concrete_model=False` with `get_for_model()`, like this:

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(proxy_obj, for_concrete_model=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the ContentType of a proxy model, you need to pass in the argument **for_concrete_model=False** into `get_for_model()`.

Example:

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(proxy_obj,
                                                 for_concrete_model=False)
```

See the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentTypeManager.get_for_model) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy_obj._meta.verbose_name.title() I think is better
```