# Django proxy-model returning wrong ContentType

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say we have a model `Company` and subtype `Client` like so:

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    related_companies = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=True)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class ClientManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return QuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).filter(is_customer=True)


class Client(Company):
    objects = ClientManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Next you go into CLI, create an instance and fetch its content-type

```py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

In[38]: company = Company.objects.create(name='test', is_customer=True)

In [39]: ContentType.objects.get_for_model(company)
Out[39]: <ContentType: contacts | company>
```

That returns the concrete model for the company class.  So far so good.

Next, according to the docs, the follows should return the Client content-type.

```py
In [40]: ContentType.objects.get_for_model(company, for_concrete_model=False)
Out[40]: <ContentType: contacts | company>
```

Yet, it does not.  I'm still receiving the concrete model Company instead of Customer

Do you see my mistake?

Comment: What is `c`? In the example it's undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ContentType.objects.get\_for\_model(obj) returning base class model when used on a proxy model object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448299/contenttype-objects-get-for-modelobj-returning-base-class-model-when-used-on-a)

Comment: @markwalker_, sorry - typo :)

Comment: @DigitalDirk Tried that, it's in my question.  It doesnt seem to yield the correct content type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `get_for_model` is done for wrong object if you expect `Client` as output.

```
In [40]: ContentType.objects.get_for_model(company, for_concrete_model=False)   
Out[40]: <ContentType: contacts | company>
```

In this code you request the `ContentType` of the `company` variable, which is a `Company` object. It is expected that this content type return `Company`.

If you follow this [the link mentioned in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448299/contenttype-objects-get-for-modelobj-returning-base-class-model-when-used-on-a), you will see that when you make a slight change to this line of your code:

```
ContentType.objects.get_for_model(company, for_concrete_model=False)
```

Change the `company` to a `Client` object so then you'll have something like this

```
client = Client.objects.create(name='test', is_customer=True)
ContentType.objects.get_for_model(client , for_concrete_model=False)
```

Return will be the Client content type.

[The django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) state the following

> get_for_model(model, for_concrete_model=True)
>
> Takes either a model class or an instance of a model, and returns the
> ContentType instance representing that model. for_concrete_model=False
> allows fetching the ContentType of a proxy model.

This means that if you set `for_concrete_model=True` and you do `get_for_model(client)` you will get the `Company` Content Type, because the Client model is a proxy model OF the Company model.

Comment: I see.  So the proxy-model won't detect which of the child models fits.  I suppose it only makes sense as many proxy models can fit the parent model.  The source of this question relates to the strawberry-django package, where requesting the Client object seems to return the Company object instead of the Client object.